# Redirect HTTP links to HTTPS with Javascript

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript

## What is the shortest way to secure a site with Javascript?

I am new to Code Golfing, and this is what I've come up with so far. I bet that this could be improved though:

### Challenge:

> Make a script which redirects `http://` to `https://` with the least bytes of code

### Attempts:

Original code (150ish BYTES!):

```
if (window.location.protocol != "https:") {
  window.location.href =
    "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
}
```

My code so far (68 bytes):

```
var l=location;':'==l.protocol[4]&&(l.href=l.href.replace(':','s:'))
```

Updated, thanks to @mypronounismonicareinstate (52 bytes):

```
l=location;l["protocol"][5]||(l["protocol"]="https")
```

Thanks to @arnauld (45 bytes):

```
(l=location)[p='protocol'][5]||(l[p]='https')
```

This works, thanks to @anderskaseorg (38 bytes):

```
with(location)protocol='https'+href[4]
```

However, this last answer would not be commonly used on a real site

Could this be minified more?

Comment: I think you want the [tag:code-golf] tag, and also check out the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges). Good luck!

Comment: I think the `==` can be replaced by `<` (because `":" < "s"`). You might also be able to skip the `var` (because if the rest of the code doesn't use global variables, this will only *help* find bugs!).

Comment: I tested in Firefox and Chrome (for some reason I don't have any other browsers installed), and simply `location.protocol='https'` seemingly can be used instead of the `l.href=...` magic.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate which leads to `(l=location)[p='protocol'][5]||(l[p]='https')` (45 bytes)

Comment: @Arnauld, I think it should be `l[p]='https:'`, 46 bytes?

Comment: @RahulVerma, `https` works too.

Comment: Note this won't make your site more secure, because the evil attacker will just delete your script as part of the attack.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You really want to be doing this on the server side, redirect to https and set headers like `Strict-Transport-Security` etc

Comment: Just to make this perfectly clear: this site is about recreational programming competitions, where only the winning criterion matters (the code size in that case). If you are _really_ looking for a clean, reliable, cross-platform compatible way to perform this task (or any other task), you definitely shouldn't be asking here.

Comment: @derder56 I mean what I said. The person who's hacking your site will just delete your script from it. So don't use this for real security.

Comment: Also your example changes file:// to files://

Answer (score 7):

## <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```javascript
with(location)protocol='https'+href[4]
```

#### How it works

- If `location.href` starts with `http:`, this assigns `location.protocol = 'https:'`.
- If `location.href` starts with `https:`, this assigns `location.protocol = 'httpss'`.  According to the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#dom-location-protocol), this should have no effect because `httpss` is neither `http` nor `https`.  Firefox obeys this specification.  Chrome seems to try to find an external app to open the `httpss` scheme ([bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=678633)).

Comment: [Use of `with` is not recommended for websites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). Alternative (a byte longer): `(l=location).protocol='https'+l.href[4]`.

Comment: @RahulVerma This is code-golf; anything that works is fair game. If you’re looking for recommended advice, stay far, far away from this entire site.

Comment: Despite of the fact that this site isn't suitable for recommended solution, `with` has _bugs and compatibility issues_, due to which it may _fail_ in some browsers.

Comment: @RahulVerma Read your link more carefully: `with` does not *have* bugs and compatibility issues, it *may be the source of* bugs and compatibility issues. If you read farther down, the described issues are in code you might write using `with` that’s confusing to humans or that might break unintuitively as JS evolves. These are valid criticisms of `with`—you should never use it—but, again, this site has *nothing to do with “should”*. The `with` statement itself behaves correctly as defined by the specification, and will not be changed; my use of `with` is not affected by these issues.

Comment: This seems ok, but it says cannot open page